# How to pass attribute value on double click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass blank value on single click function and want to redirect on double click.

Here my code for HTML

[image]

Code for j-query

```
$(function () {

        var clicker = $('#Nav a');

        $(this).click(function () {
            $(this).attr('href', '');
        });

        clicker.dblclick(function () {
            window.location = $(this).attr("href");
        });
}
```

kindly suggest how i can pass same attribute value for two different function or any other way to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **[e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)** to prevent redirection on single click:

```
$(function () {

    var clicker = $('#Nav a');

    clicker.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    clicker.dblclick(function () {
        window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    });
})
```

Also, note that `$(this)` of your click function is not map to any element at this moment. Since you've assigned `var clicker = $('#Nav a')` then you can use `clicker.click` instead.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/afA4X/1/)**

Comment: Can you please tell me how we can implement double click function of jquery in I-pad devices.Because dblclick function not worked in I-pad devices. So how i can use same code for double click.